# Undefined offset: 5 in PHP for the Below Code

Tags: php

Hi I am getting Undefined Offset for the below code.

```
            <?php
    function readCSV($fileName) {
      $rows = array();
      $rows = file($fileName);
      $max = sizeof($rows);
          for ($x=0; $x<=$max; $x++) {
      echo "<li> <a href='#".$rows[$x]."'>$rows[$x]</a> </li>";

} 

      return $rows;
}   

?>

  <span><b>Available Positions: </b></span>
  <ul>
 <? (readCSV('joinUs.csv');?>
  </ul>
```

Please let me know where I am making mistake in the above code.

Thanks

Comment: change to `$x < $max`.

Comment: Check this out: http://nl3.php.net/fgetcsv

Comment: change `for ($x=0; $x<=$max; $x++)` to `for ($x=0; $x < $max; $x++)`

Comment: I don't know why this question is marked as duplicate with the referenced question. there is no resemblance except for the title

Comment: This Question has a specific code I dont Understand why you have marked this question as duplicate.I request you to remove duplicate mark.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 for ($x=0; $x<=$max; $x++)
```

to

```
for ($x=0; $x < $max; $x++)
```

should work like maska..
 :)

since the count starts from `0` the for loop should be used with a condition of `1` less of your `max` condition.
A simple counting funda.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a key which has not been set in your for loop.

```
for ($x=0; $x < $max; $x++) {
   echo "<li> <a href='#".$rows[$x]."'>$rows[$x]</a> </li>";
}
```